# How to use dates and numbers separately with LUIS.ai?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm testing LUIS.ai and I'm following the introduction that I saw on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWeLajon9M8), but I'm doing it in French because I need it. So I'm writing some utterances for an intent but I have a problem with prebuilt entities "Date" and "Number".

Indeed when I want it to detect a date, I'm using the prebuilt entity "Date" on the suitable pattern, but the problem is that every number and date are automatically detected as dates, and I don't find how to remove the date entity from the pattern it is directly applied to. And if I completely delete the date entity but bring the prebuilt number entity, every number are detected as numbers, but I can't bring back the date entity in the same time because the date entity will remove the number entity and force itself on numbers.

For example : I have the utterance "je voudrais réserver un billet d'avion pour paris pour le 30 mars" which means "I would like to book a flight to Paris on the 30th of March". Here I can select "Paris" and tell that it is associated to a "Destination" entity that i created, but if I select "30 mars" (30h of March) and add the prebuilt entity date, it will detect it as a date (this one is fine), but it will also automaticcaly detect "un" ("1" in French) as a date, and I can't do anything about it, I can't remove it.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? Because of course I don't want numbers to be detected as dates and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UI issue more than anything and not likely one to change.

You can't change detection of pre-built entities (like `number` or `dateTimeV2`). So, clicking on a detected pre-built entity won't really help.

However, LUIS returns *all* detected entities.

From the Test panel:

[image]

In the JSON:

[image]

Assuming you're using this in a bot of some kind, just have your bot detect whether or not an entity is present on a recognized result.

Comment: I didn't realise the number entity could be also detected because I removed it immediately after importing the date entity, because it was not directly displayed on the screen, so I thought it was not counted. Now I have the two entities and both are detected ! Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. It's a bit confusing and you're not the first person to have this issue. I'll file a feature request and see if they can come up with a better UI for this.